What is the energy of Majorana bound states when a topological superconductor is connected to a voltage source?
I am reading about some models that describe Majorana bound states in semiconducting nanowires. When tunnel spectroscopy experiments are modelled, where a topological superconducting nanowire is coupled, for example, to a normal metal wire, the energy of the two Majoranas at the two ends of topological superconducting nanowire is usually taken to be zero (Hamiltonian for topological superconductor holding two Majoranas,  HTS= E γ1 γ2; where energy E=0). Is this related to the topological superconductor being grounded? And what if there are two topological superconductors tunnel coupled as in the sketch below. There would also be Cooper pair tunneling between the superconductors (in addition to Majoranas tunneling), but I am only interested if the energy E of the topological superconductor  connected to a voltage source (as shown in the sketch below).
Can energy of the second topological superconductor Hamiltonian in the figure below also be taken to zero when that topological superconductor is connected to a voltage source (HTS2=ETS2 γ3 γ4; where ETS2=0)?

